# Raising heels in kedusha according to Chacham Ovadia

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilla, kedusha-prayer, hacham-ovadia-yosef

[Halacha Yomit](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=1769) says that Chacham Ovadia rules that one must raise his heels 3 times each in every kadosh. Where can the source for this halacha be found in Chacham Ovadia's books?

Comment: ALso YO OC 6:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef 125:6](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_all.html#HtmpReportNum0128_L2):

> נוהגים לדלג מעט ולהרים עקבו מן הקרקע כשאומר פסוק ''קדוש'' ופסוק ''ברוך'' ופסוק ''ימלוך'' בקדושה. וכשאומר פסוק ''קדוש'', ידלג שלש פעמים בכל פעם שאומר ''קדוש''.‏
>
> The custom is to jump slightly and raise one's heels from the ground when saying the verses "kadosh", "baruch" and "yimloch" in *kedushah*. When one says the verse "kadosh", one should jump three times, each time he says the word "kadosh".

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. This work was written by R' Ovadia Yosef's son

Comment: @DoubleAA and reviewed comprehensively by R Ovadia

Comment: But you're right that technically this isn't one of "Chacham Ovadia's books"

Comment: the comma in the answer changes the meaning (בכל פעם שאומר ''קדוש'') -- is it three times, for each kadosh, or three times for each kadosh?

Comment: Each time one says, “Kadosh”, a rise of the heels is done. It parallels the behavior of the Ofanim & Chayot HaKodesh which ascend to the place of the Seraphim.